# 1 rectangle <= 4 squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrepancy-theory, gr.group-theory

Almost 25 years ago a professor at Indiana U showed me the following problem:

given a map $\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that the sum inside every square (parallel to the axes) is $\leq1$ in absolute value, prove that the sum inside every rectangle (parallel to axes) is $\leq4$ in absolute value.

It's fun and not too hard to prove.
I believe that at the time I was able to show that the upper limit can be improved to 3.975 - but that was a lot harder and I can't say now that this is for sure the case.  Also, with a computer search (old TRS 80) I produced an example containing a rectangle of area $3\frac{1}{3}$.

These are some of the questions that come to mind:

- can the upper limit of 4 (or 3.975?) be improved?
- can the lower limit of $3\frac{1}{3}$ be improved?
- any proof/conjecture about the optimal limit?
- do the results extend to maps $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, provided they are "nice" enough?
- are any other generalizations of this problem possible (eg. different tilings of the plane or of other manifolds, or higher dimensions)?

**Update 1 (updated 7th March 2010)**. See answers and comments below  for examples achieving ratios as high as 181/48 = 3.7708333...!

**Update 2**. Here is a sketch of the proof that 4 is an upper limit.
A limit of 254/67=3.79104477... is now known (see answers below), but the proof for that needs to be seeded with at least some known limit.

Given a rectangle R of size AxB, with A < B, call it "thin" if $B\geq2A$ or "fat" if $B\leq2A$ (the case B=2A is irrelevant as it is the union of 2 squares).
One can draw the 4 squares on the sides of R, either facing outwards (size of envelope = (2B+A)x(2A+B)), or inwards (some spilling out on the opposite sides, size of envelope = (2B-A)xB) - call these the "big-envelope" and the "small-envelope".

Assume that R has sum 4+$\epsilon$ and that every square has sum between -1 and 1. We have 3 cases, all easy exercises to work out:

(1) for any R, the fat (2A+B)x(2B+A) big-envelope will have sum $\leq-4-3\epsilon$.

(2) for a fat R, a (2A-B)x(2B-A) sub-rectangle of the small-envelope will have sum $\leq-4-3\epsilon$;

(3) for a thin R, a thin (B-2A)x(2B-A) sub-rectangle of the small-envelope, will have sum $\geq4+3\epsilon$;

Applying any of (1)+(2), (2)+(1) or (3)+(3) produces a 3Ax3B rectangle with
sum $\geq4+9\epsilon$.  Iterating n times produces a $3^{n}A \times 3^{n}B$ rectangle with sum $4+9^{n}\epsilon$.  Such rectangle is made of no more than AxB squares (each of size $3^{n} \times 3^{n}$) and therefore, for large enough n, one of the squares will have sum >1. $\square$

**Reformulation** . Given an abelian group G and a map

f: GxGxGxG -> $\mathbb{R}$  such that

1) -1<=f(a,b,c,d)<=1  if d*a=c*b
(boundedness of squares),

2) f(a,b,c,d)+f(c,b,e,d)=f(a,b,e,d)  for all a, b, c, d, e in G
(horizontal additivity of rectangles),

3) f(a,b,c,d)+f(a,d,c,e)=f(a,b,c,e)  for all a, b, c, d, e in G
(vertical additivity of rectangles),

can we find a universal best bound b(G) such that -b(G) <= f <= b(G)?

All the previous work on this question amounts to the result:
181/48 <= b($\mathbb{Z}$) <= b($\mathbb{Z}x\mathbb{Z}$) <= 254/67

For non-abelian groups one could perhaps generalize the notion of "square"
by lifting it from G/[G,G].

Comment: Are your squares and rectangles parallel to the coordinate axes?
Does your sum include all points on or inside the square/rectangle, or just the points on the boundary (or just the corners)?

Comment: I still found the question hard to understand. Lemme just check: is it the following? given f:Z^2->R with, for all integers i,j and N>=0, |sum_{i<=x<=i+N,j<=y<=j+N}f(x,y)|<=1, then for all i,j and M,N>=0, |sum_{i<=x<=i+N,j<=y<=j+M}f(x,y)|<=4? I'm not saying you should rewrite it like this, I just don't have a very geometric mind.

Comment: Kevin, your restatement is correct.  I wrote the question the way I did because the proof I know is geometric.

Comment: Professor's name?

Comment: Hari Berkovici.

Comment: or more likely Bercovici

Comment: Why not give the proofs for 4 and 10/3?

Comment: Interesting problem/result. One question: why the "measure-theory" tag?

Comment: I agree it's questionable tag, unless perhaps we thing in terms of some generalized theory that allows negative measures (is there such?). I added "integration" and "inequalities" and I'm open to any suggestion, including removing "measure-theory".

Comment: I retagged to combinatorics and created a discrepancy-theory tag. It's possible that nt.number-theory would fit, since this is within combinatorial number theory and some discrepancy theory papers get tagged nt, but I think that's misleading. Although this is "puzzling" and can be described using "integrals" over "measures," I don't think those fit as tags.

Comment: would it make sense to ask the following in R^2 for C^-1 functions: if the integral for a function f is limited  between +-1 on each disk, is there a limit on every convex set?

Comment: This whole page is becoming messy...  I have a comment to one of Tony's answers below about the 3.8 limit, but perhaps should we all agree to post future comments only to the main question or the most recent answer? (We should try to limit the use of updates to significant developments only, lest other users object to this question getting bumped to first page too often.)

Comment: I have setup a Google Docs page to record progress on this problem, hopefully we can stop continually updating this page. It is at 
http://docs.google.com/View?id=ajkfbpjb4hfn_182c4hq2qfj 
If you want to help edit the page, send me an email ; by the way, for those following the search for better configurations, there is something new there (a new 1x12 solution ...)

Comment: The group theoretic version could be formulated this way too: given an abelian group G and all maps f: GxG->R such that -1<=f(c,d)-f(a,d)-f(c,b)+f(a,b)<=1 for all a,b,c,d in G such that ad=bc, then find the a best limit B(G) such that -B(G)<=f(c,d)-f(a,d)-f(c,b)+f(a,b)<=B(G) for all a,b,c,d in G. It is easy to prove that B(G/H)<=B(G) for any group G and subgroup H, by lifting any example f: G/HxG/H->R to an example F:GxG->R via the canonical projection.

Comment: B(Z/2)=B(Z/3)=1, B(Z/4)=B(Z/5)=2.

Comment: It seems that B(Z/2 x Z/2)=3, but I need to check my calculations (basically the awk program provided in one of the older answers below, modified to do arithmetic mod 2).

Comment: I think I was wrong in the main question where I stated that b(ZxZ)<=254/67. What is true is that if f is bounded on rectangles, then f(any rectangle)<=254/67. But I don't see a way to eliminate the possibility of a runaway f (i.e. unbounded on rectangles). I'll correct the main question if/when I have something else of substance to add.

Answer (score 13):

A computer search led to the following 16x16 example with a **7/2** rectangle in the middle (scale everything by 1/12):

```
 0  -3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -6   6   0   0   0
-1   1  -3   0   3   3  -3   0   0  -3   0   6   0  -3   0   0
 4   2   0   0 -12   9  -3   0   0   0   9 -12   0  -3   6   0
-6   0   0   0   6 -12  12  -6   0  12 -12   3   3   2  -2  -6
 6   0   0   0   6   0 -12   6  12 -12   0   3   2  -1  -4  12
-3   0   0   0  -3   2  -2   0  -6   6  -6  12  -5  -7   0   0
 0   0   0   0   3   4  -4  -6   0 -12  12  -6   0  12   0  -6
 0   0   0   0  -6 -12  12   6  12  12 -12  -6   0   0   0   0
 0   9  -6   0   6   2  -2  -4  -2 -10  10   0   5  -9  -2   0
 3  -3   0   0   0   4  -4  -2  -4   4  -4   6   0   4   2  -6
 0  -6   6   0   0   0 -12   6  12 -12   0  -3  -2   1   4   6
-6   0   0   0   6 -12  12   2  -8  12 -12   3   3   0   0  -6
 8   0  -6   4 -12   9   3  -5  -1   0   9  -6  -4   4   0   3
 0   0   0  -4   4   0   0   3  -7   0   3   1  -2  -1  -4   3
-2   0   3  -1   0   3   0  -1   2   0  -6  -1   7   0   0   0
-3   0   6   1   0  -4   0   1  -1  -3   3   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Update** : using Leonid's remark on imposing symmetry w.l.o.g., here is a smaller and symmetric 13x16 example with a 7/2 rectangle (scale by 1/4):

```
 0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0 -2 -2  4 -1  0  0 -1  4 -2 -2  0  0  1
-2  0  0  2  0 -4  4 -1 -1  4 -4  0  2  0  0 -2
 1  0  0  0  0  0 -4  3  3 -4  0  0  0  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  2 -2 -1 -1 -2  2  2  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0 -2 -4  4  3  3  4 -4 -2  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  2 -2 -1 -1 -2  2  2  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0  0  0 -4  3  3 -4  0  0  0  0  0  1
-2  0  0  2  0 -4  4 -1 -1  4 -4  0  2  0  0 -2
 1  0  0 -2 -2  4 -1  0  0 -1  4 -2 -2  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0
```

I also tried to find an example with a ratio better than 7/2, keeping the symmetry and a 1x4 rectangle in the middle, but could not find any (the largest size I am able to check is 33x38).

Comment: twice awesome!
(Twice because comments are 15 chars minimum.)

Comment: notice that specific AxB rectangles may encounter lower upper bounds than the general case.  In particular the above proof of 4 as an upper bound, shows that a sum of 4 for a 4x1 rectangles would imply also a sum of 4 for a 6x9, which is a union of 3 squares. From this one can work out some stricter limit on the 4x1, but I haven't got around to computing it

Comment: Your epsilon doesn't have to be positive, right? So if a 4x1 rectangle has sum >= 4 - epsilon, then the 6x9 rectangle has sum >= -4 + 3*epsilon, which is impossible if epsilon < 1/3. So a 4x1 rectangle has sum <= 11/3.

The same is true for 7x8 (because (2A-B)x(2B-A) = 6x9) and 1x5 (because (B-2A)x(2B-A) = 3x9).

Comment: I don't think one can play with the sign of epsilon just like that (i.e. without checking the details), since we are dealing with one-sided inequalities and not purely linear equations, BUT I did check out the (2A+B)x(2B+A) details for AxB=1x4 and it is quite easy to see that your conclusion indeed holds and the 1x4 can never exceed a sum of 11/3. I'd be surprised if the same limit doesn't hold for 7x8 and 1x5, as you pointed out, but again I would have to look at the details to be sure.

As an aside, I also worked out a little example of a 1x3 which achieves its maximum allowed sum of 3.


Comment: One more comment on Leonid's example: if extended to a map on R^2 (real plane) by extending each entry uniformly on a 1x1 square, the ratio achieved is 2.8 (the best I've seen on the reals so far). Clearly an upper limit for Z^2 will induce the same upper limit on R^2 and the set of C^-1 function (i.e. those with continuous integrals), because for such functions any real rectangle can be approximated by rational ones. Similarly an example in R with ratio r will produce examples in Z with ratios arbitrarily close to r. So upper and lower limits for R are <= those for Z.

Comment: (PREVIOUS COMMENT DELETED) I've looked at the other cases too (7x8 and 1x5), and everything seems to work, whatever the value of epsilon. By the way, what is your 1x3 example?

Comment: Regard //s as new lines:// -1 1 -1 1 -1 // 0 0 0 0 0 // 1 -1 0 -1 1 // -1 1 1 1 -1 // 1 -1 0 -1 1 // 0 0 0 0 0 // -1 1 -1 1-1 // 

Comment: CORRECTION: what I referred to above as "Leonid's example", should have read "FG's" example instead

Comment: We can iterate this process if we like. For instance, a 2x7 rectangle must have sum <= 35/9, because (B-2A)x(2B-A) = 3x12, which is 1x4, which has sum <= 11/3. Which rectangles can be limited to strictly less than 4 in this way?

Comment: My computer and I have looked at this, and it seems that almost no rectangles can be limited in this way. A quick search with m < n < 4096 found just 72 limitable rectangles with (m,n) = 1.

Comment: for thin rectangles there are easy limits of the type 4+n*epsilon for all {2A,B+2A,B-2A}x{2B+A,2B-A}, n=2,3,4 or even 5 - but nonetheless, this is a limited way forward.  I think going deeper into the tree of cases for different degrees of thinness and more complicated envelopes would yield a universal limit <4.

Comment: A 1x4 cannot have sum more than 7/2, i.e. FG's example is best possible for 1x4. This can be seen working inside the 9x6 envelope... use the fact that the 4x2 which includes (and is limited on a side by) the 2 central units of the 1x4, has sum <=2.

Comment: Sorry, Yaakov, but I can't see it. Can you say a bit more please?

Comment: Write AxB+C+D for R with vertices (C,D), (C+A,D), (C,D+B), (C+A,D+B). Now let R=1x4+3+0. Then 1x1+3+0=1x1+3+3=1-a, 1x1+3+1=1x1+3+2=1-b, 4x4+0+0=1-e and 3x3+0+0=3x3+0+1=-1+g, for a,b,e,g>=0. Then work out that 4x2+0+1=3-2a-4b+e+2g but any 4x2<=2 implies 2a+4b>=1, implies 2a+2b>=1/2, implies R=4-2a-2b<=7/2.

Answer (score 10):

The upper bound is <3.95.

I hope the code below will show correctly...

It proves that assuming a sum >=3.95 in the central AxB rectangle of the grid
({-B,-B+A,-2A,-A,0,A,2A,B-A,B}+{0,A}) x ({-2B,-B-A,-B,-B+A,-2A,-A,0,A,2A,B-A,B,B+A,2B}+{0,B})
leads to a contradiction in a finite number of steps.  3.95 is NOT best possible for this grid, but 3.94 does not lead to a contradiction.  It will be easy to refine the number, but
more worthwhile is probably to search a larger grid (which starts to get slow in awk.)

```
awk 'BEGIN {

 A=1;
 # pick B large enough to ensure that there
 # are no accidental squares in the grid below
 B=1000;

 # setting up the grid
 x[0]=-B;       x[1]=-B+A;
 x[1]=-B+A;     x[2]=-B+2*A;
 x[3]=-2*A;     x[4]=-A;
 x[4]=-A;       x[5]=0;
 x[5]=0;        x[6]=A;
 x[6]=A;        x[7]=2*A;
 x[7]=2*A;      x[8]=3*A;
 x[9]=B-A;     x[10]=B;
 x[10]=B;       x[11]=B+A;
 M=11;

 y[0]=-2*B;     y[2]=-B;
 y[1]=-B-A;     y[5]=-A;
 y[2]=-B;       y[6]=0;
 y[3]=-B+A;     y[7]=A;
 y[4]=-2*A;     y[9]=B-2*A;
 y[5]=-A;       y[10]=B-A;
 y[6]=0;        y[11]=B;
 y[7]=A;        y[12]=B+A;
 y[8]=2*A;      y[13]=B+2*A;
 y[10]=B-A;     y[14]=B+B-A;
 y[11]=B;       y[15]=B+B;
 y[12]=B+A;     y[16]=B+B+A;
 y[15]=2*B;     y[17]=3*B;
 N=17;

 for(i=0; i<=M; i++)
     for(j=i; j<=M; j++)
         for(k=0; k<=N; k++)
             for(l=k; l<=N; l++)
                 # 0 sum for degenerate rectangles
                 if(i==j || k==l) {
                     lo[i,j,k,l]=0;
                     hi[i,j,k,l]=0;
                 }                   
                 # squares
                 else if(x[j]-x[i]==y[l]-y[k]) {
                     lo[i,j,k,l]=-1;
                     hi[i,j,k,l]=1;
                 }
                 # other rectangles
                 else {
                     lo[i,j,k,l]=-4;
                     hi[i,j,k,l]=4;
                 }

 # central rectangle: assume its sum is >=3.95
 lo[5,6,6,11]=3.95;

 iter=10000;
 active=1;
 while(iter-- && active) {
     active=0;

     # traverse all possible combinations of 1 rectangle split into 4
     for(i=0; i<M; i++)
         for(j=i+1; j<=M; j++)
             for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                 for(l=k+1; l<=N; l++)
                     for(m=i; m<j; m++)
                         for(n=k; n<l; n++) {
                             lo0=lo[i,j,k,l];
                             lo1=lo[i,m,k,n];
                             lo2=lo[m,j,k,n];
                             lo3=lo[i,m,n,l];
                             lo4=lo[m,j,n,l];
                             hi0=hi[i,j,k,l];
                             hi1=hi[i,m,k,n];
                             hi2=hi[m,j,k,n];
                             hi3=hi[i,m,n,l];
                             hi4=hi[m,j,n,l];

                             # 3rd argument in max() and min() funtions
                             # is for printing purposes only...
                             lo0=max(lo0, lo1+lo2+lo3+lo4, 0);
                             hi0=min(hi0, hi1+hi2+hi3+hi4, 0);
                             lo1=max(lo1, lo0-hi2-hi3-hi4, 1);
                             lo2=max(lo2, lo0-hi1-hi3-hi4, 2);
                             lo3=max(lo3, lo0-hi1-hi2-hi4, 3);
                             lo4=max(lo4, lo0-hi1-hi2-hi3, 4);
                             hi1=min(hi1, hi0-lo2-lo3-lo4, 1);
                             hi2=min(hi2, hi0-lo1-lo3-lo4, 2);
                             hi3=min(hi3, hi0-lo1-lo2-lo4, 3);
                             hi4=min(hi4, hi0-lo1-lo2-lo3, 4);

                             if(lo0>hi0 || lo1>hi1 || lo2>hi2 || lo3>hi3 || lo4>hi4) {
                                 print "CONTRADICTION AT", i,m,j,k,n,l;
                                 exit;
                             }

                             lo[i,j,k,l]=lo0;
                             lo[i,m,k,n]=lo1;
                             lo[m,j,k,n]=lo2;
                             lo[i,m,n,l]=lo3;
                             lo[m,j,n,l]=lo4;
                             hi[i,j,k,l]=hi0;
                             hi[i,m,k,n]=hi1;
                             hi[m,j,k,n]=hi2;
                             hi[i,m,n,l]=hi3;
                             hi[m,j,n,l]=hi4;
                         }
 }
 print "FINISHED OK";
}

function max(s,t, where) {

if(s<t) {
    print "lo=" t, "for", i,m,j,k,n,l, "(" where ")";
    active=1;
    s=t;
}
return(s);
}

function min(s,t, where) {

if(s>t) {
    print "hi=" t, "for", i,m,j,k,n,l, "(" where ")";
    active=1;
    s=t;
}
return(s);
}
'
```

Comment: This a preemptive comment:  one could argue that I'm proving the result only for thin enough rectangles (as hinted by my pick of a huge
B=1000).  However this is not essential.  If one thinks in term of "negative rectangles" it is easy to see that set of constraints imposed by the key decomposition of one rectangle in 4 sub-rectangles, remains the same.

Comment: I have used your program to do a binary search for the limiting value. For the grid that you use, it turns out to be exactly 154/39 = 3.9487...

Comment: Tony, thank you.  I tried enlarging the x grid to
{-2B,-B-A,-B,-B+A,-2A,-A,0,A,2A,B-A,B,B+A,2B}+{0,A} but 3.945 is still out of reach.  By the way, I find mawk to be a little faster than either awk or gawk (of course perl would be even better, or C if one had the patience).

Comment: I converted it to C++ before I ran it. It didn't take long. I will play around with the grid sizes when I have some time.

Comment: Another update: assuming the already proven limits of -3.95 and +3.95 for all rectangles, then 3.945 is a limit! (This works even with the original 12x18 grid.)

Comment: I have been trying this idea in parallel with you. If we replace 4 with 154/39 as the maximum value for all rectangles, then we get a new, smaller limit, r say. And now we can replace 154/39 with r, and so on. I have iterated this process by hand, and it reaches a limit of 3.944444... = 71/18.
The question is whether this iteration is a substitute for using a larger grid, or whether a larger grid is really needed to get better limits.

Comment: What happens if you use 71/18 instead of 4 in your larger grid, Yaakov?

Comment: This is where I'm at now:

KNOWN_BOUND=3.94445;
TEST_BOUND=3.94;

x grid as before

y[0]=-3*B; y[1]=-2*B-A; y[2]=-2*B; y[3]=-2*B+A; y[4]=-B-2*A; y[5]=-B-A; y[6]=-B; y[7]=-B+A; y[8]=-B+2*A; y[9]=-3*A; y[10]=-2*A; y[11]=-A; y[12]=0; y[13]=A; y[14]=2*A; y[15]=3*A; y[16]=B-3*A; y[17]=B-2*A; y[18]=B-A; y[19]=B; y[20]=B+A; y[21]=B+2*A; y[22]=B+3*A; y[23]=2*B-2*A; y[24]=2*B-A; y[25]=2*B; y[26]=2*B+A; y[27]=2*B+2*A; y[28]=3*B-A; y[29]=3*B; y[30]=3*B+A; y[31]=4*B; N=31;
...
lo[5,6,12,19]=TEST_BOUND;

(and it succeeded - 3.94 is a new limit.  But awk is killing me.)

Comment: I'll be off internet for next 28 hour.

Comment: Using your enlarged x and y grids (18 x 32), and iterating as above, I can get down to 47/12 = 3.916666...
By the way, if you are using the larger x grid in your above comment, then lo[5,6,12,19] should be lo[8,9,12,19].

Comment: Now I am using generated grids: the x-grid is {m*A + n*B} + {0,A}, and the y-grid is {m*A + n*B} + {0, B}, for all m,n with |m| <= L and |n| <= L, for some parameter L. With L = 2, we get a 30x30 grid, and the iteration process results in a bound of 19/5 = 3.8 (!). I am going to try L=3, but it will be slow...

Comment: 3.8 is stunning!  One can also use this tool will small B's (instead of 1000), to find upper limits for 1x5, 1x6, 2x7 etc. (like the 3.5 we have for 1x4), and then based on that one can better focus a search for a higher low bound... With these low B's one of course has to make sure that the x and y array are sorted by value (or else create special cases in the code for when (x[m],y[n]) lies outside the rectangle defined by (x[i],y[k]) and (x[j],y[l]).

Comment: Now, here's a surprise: with L = 3, and a 56 x 56 grid, there is no improvement: it's still 3.8! And L = 4 is beyond my reach.

Comment: I suspect that |m|+|n|<L may produce better grids... but this is just a hunch.  Similarly I suspect that lopsided grids (more points for, say, y than x) may be more effective than symmetric ones.

Comment: Not so in this case. I tried L = 2 in one direction and L = 4 in the other, for a 30 x 90 grid, and it still got stuck at 3.80.

Comment: I just realized (fun exercise) that the set of inequalities derived from decomposing rectangles into 2 in all ways (cutting vertically or horizontally) imply the set of inequalities derived from splitting rectangles into 4. Since the first approach involves 5 nested loops instead of 6, it is MUCH faster for large grids.  For a medium grid I timed a speed improvement 6x.

Answer (score 10):

**Latest figures**

FG has posted [a solution for the 12x1 rectangle](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/217239/sol_rectangle.html), attaining 181/48 = 3.3.7708333...

More results:
11x1 rectangle is 101/27 = 3.740740...
7x3 rectangle is 56/15 = 3.733333...
7x2 rectangle is 67/18 = 3.722222...
8x1 rectangle is 26/7 = 3.714285...
6x1 rectangle is 85/23 = 3.695652...
7x1 rectangle is 11/3 = 3.666666...
5x1 rectangle is 25/7 = 3.571428...

I have removed specific solutions from this answer, as they have been superseded by FG's results.

Comment: TonyK, this is great ! I thought for a while that 3.5 could not be beaten, but I was looking at wrong (central rectangle/grid) size combinations (mostly too small grids).

Comment: As far as I can check, 25/7 can also be obtained on a smaller 23x29 grid ; 31x36 seems optimal for 85/23.

Comment: Yes, LK, the upper bounds are proved. (But the program uses floating-point arithmetic. For a proper computer-assisted proof, I suppose it would need to use rationals.)

Comment: TonyK, I can confirm 26/7 is possible for a 1x8 rectangle within a 39x46 grid. Maybe we can discuss how we obtain those grids ? I use a linear programming formulation (a variable for every cell, a constraint for every square), which is quick (optimally solved in less than a minute) but runs out of memory around the 45x45 size (too many squares - it should be possible to remove some redundancies). 

Comment: Once you have a consistent and non-improvable set of bounds, you can collapse one interval to a point within, one rectangle at a time, then refresh the set of bounds and repeat the procedure until all intervals have shrunk to a point. Unfortunately, I don't know if one can also collapse the 3 (or 1) symmetric images of the chosen rectangle without a refresh in between.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, Yaakov. But it's terribly slow. FG has a much better method -- one minute, instead of a day or two! Can you say a bit more about it, FG? And perhaps you could post your solution for the 8x1 rectangle.

Comment: Also, FG, have you built the symmetry into your model? So that you only need 23x23 variables for a 45x45 grid?

Comment: The problem with my 1x8 test is that the solution I get does not seem to be easy to round nicely like the previous ones (some factors are obvious, like 7, but others seem inconsistent). Anyway, I put it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/217239/sol_rectangle.html
I am using the symmetry.

Comment: OK, I have now a new model that is much easier to solver (uses sparser constraints) - I can confirm that 2x7 leads indeed to 67/18. And 3x7 leads to 56/15. More coming later today ... 

Comment: this thread beats a lot of good novels!

Comment: FG, is your software able to look for integer solutions? If so, you can set the square constraint to |sum| <= 15,and the central 3x7 rectangle to 56. Then the solution will be much nicer, and probably faster to find.

(What software are you using?)

Comment: I've just had a look at some linear programming pages, and it seems that searching for integer solutions is slower, not faster. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

I remember reading about this in the Geometric Discrepancy book of Matousek. Another way of putting your statement is that if the discrepancy of squares is small, then so is that of rectangles. I think that the higher dimensional version of expressing the characteristic vector of a brick with characteristic vectors of cubes is still open. Here is a recent related paper that might be interesting for you to find the exact bound for your question:
http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~walters/papers/rectangles-as-sums-of-squares.pdf

Comment: The paper seems related to the topic, but not useful to providing any bounds, because here squares and rectangles can form equations with signs and multiplicities, while in the paper they only form disjoint unions

Comment: They discuss the "plus/minus problem" as well: *We prove polylogarithmic `(C(log n)d)` upper and lower bounds for the number of hypercubes needed to tile a hypercuboid in either of the above senses. In more than two dimensions this is a huge improvement on anything previously known. It was not even known whether an `n × 1 × 1` cuboid could be tiled with fewer than n cubes in the plus/minus sense.* (page 3)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick description of the linear programming formulation I used to compute some configurations:

Given a $m \times n$ grid $G$, one can describe a configuration with a real vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Then, for each square featuring a nonempty intersection with $G$, one can write down an indicator vector $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$ ($i \in S$), whose components are equal to $1$ if in the square, and $0$ otherwise. Finally, one can write $c \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$, the indicator of the rectangle whose sum is to be maximized.

The linear program is then $$ \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}} c^T x \text{ such that } -1 \le a_i^T x \le 1\ \forall i \in S$$
This type of program can be solved extremely efficiently up to relatively large sizes $mn$ (I am using the ILOG CPLEX solver).

Taking into account the symmetry is straightforward: if you want several components of $x$ to be equal to each other, only keep one of them and adapt the remaining coefficients in $c$ and $a_i$ (i.e. replace them with the sum of the corresponding coefficients).

However, this approach has limitations because there are a lot of vectors $a_i$, and those vectors have sometimes a lot of nonzero components (which has an influence on the efficiency of the solver and crucially on the memory used). I was only able to use it up to around a $45\times 45$ grid.

To obtain solutions for larger sizes, I used the following trick: instead of defining variable $x_{ij}$ for the content of the $(i,j)$ cell in the grid, I define variable $y_{i,j}$ as follows $$ y_{i,j} = \sum_{1\le k\le i, 1\le l \le j} x_{k,l}.$$ Then it can be checked that the sum of the square or rectangle with opposite corners $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is equal to $y_{c,d}+y_{a-1,b-1}-y_{c,b-1}-y_{a-1,d}$. This means each constraint in the corresponding linear program will have at most $4$ nonzeros, which improves a lot the speed and memory requirements of the solver.

By the way, I will put my latest results in the link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/217239/sol_rectangle.html

The current largest solution ($56/15$ for a $3\times 7$ rectangle), is made of fractions with common denominator 120, but this is just a happy coincidence, for nothing forces that in the linear program (and, as remarked by TonyK, enforcing it explicitly would be very costly).

**Update** I have run an extensive set of runs for rectangle sizes below 20x20 and put the results at the end of the file linked above. The record is still $56/15$, which is attained by many rectangles (notably by the $1 \times 9$ on a $101\times 109$ grid). It seems like even larger grids will be needed to obtain larger sums.

**Update2** $1 \times 11$ in a $137 \times 63$ grid gives $101/27$=**3.7407407**

**Update3** $1 \times 12$ in a $155 \times 68$ grid gives $15/4$=**3.75**

Unfortunately, I can only check $1 \times 13$ up to around $191\times 77$, which still gives 3.75, and I seem to have exhausted my tricks for the moment ...

Comment: I can confirm that FG's 3x7 solution attains 56/15. Well done!

Comment: the update is impressive.  Shouldn't it be part of an update to the main question itself?

Comment: I can confirm the 101/27 result. I also checked the real case (no surprises) and I'm updating the related post.

Comment: I can confirm your new 15/4 result for the 12x1 rectangle. (And your first two rows are all zero, so the rectangle is really 157x82.)

Comment: And I can confirm your 155x68 result too.

Comment: Given that 7x1 was no improvement on 6x1, perhaps it might be worth  trying 14x1 or 15x1.

Comment: I can confirm your latest result for the 12x1 rectangle in a 241x126 grid. (And the first five rows are all zero, so the grid is really 231x126.) 181/48 = 3.7708333...! That's more than 3.75, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a summary for the $\mathbb{R}^2$ situation.

Upper limit: no improvement over the 3.8 known on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

To create specific examples I modified the $\mathbb{Z}^2$ ones by uniformely
spreading each value on the lattice over a 1x1 square:

3x1:  ratio = 3-3/5 (vs. 3 on integers, 7x5 grid)
4x1:  ratio = 3-1/5 (vs. 3.5 on integers, 13x16 grid)
5x1:  ratio = 3-1/7 (vs. 25/7 on integers, 25x29 grid)
6x1:  ratio = 3-1/23 (vs. 85/23 on integers, 31x36 grid)
8x1:  ratio = 3-1/35 (vs. 26/7 on integers, 39x46 grid)
7x3:  ratio = 3-1/75 (vs. 56/15 on integers, 59x57 grid)
11x1: ratio = 3-1/135 (vs. 101/27 on integers, 137x63 grid)

And the surprises are
1) that in all cases the highest sum on a square is 1.25 that of the integral case (which is the worst case scenario, but I see no obvious reason it should always be that way), and
2) we seem to be approaching 3, suggesting that for the integers perhaps the upper limit could be 3.75 and not 3.8 - but this is of course very highly speculative...

Comment: I bet you it's 3.8.

Comment: An idea: if L=4 there are rectangles of size Ax4A, 4AxA, Bx4B and 4BxB on which we can impose the known limit of 3.5, rather than 3.8 - well, that won't help any because the proof of a 3.5 on a 4x1 was all contained in a 4x4, and the L=4 grid contains the 4Ax4A and 4Bx4B needed for the proof!
However, and THIS is the idea, if L=5 in one direction, the limit of 25/7 for Ax5A etc. is not contained in the grid and so imposing that could add the extra oomph to break the 3.8 barrier. I'd try L=2 in one direction and L=5 in the other, with those 25/7 limits... Even if that fails, I bet on 3.75.

Comment: I also bet on 3.75 (and have for the moment nothing better to report than 56/15 on the lower bound front).

Comment: Correction: there are of course Ax5A and similar rectangles for L=3
(since m,n range from -3 to +3).  Also, the limits 2 on Ax2A, 3 on Ax3A, 3.5 on Ax4A etc., while achievable by the program, nonetheless could make it run faster if imposed from the outset.

Comment: I have just tried L=3 in one direction and L=5 in the other, and I still get 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new upper bound of 254/67 (= 3.79104477...).

Define 6 sets of cardinality 4:

X1={-B+A, 0, A, B}
Y1={0, A, B-A, B}

X2={-B, -B+3A, B-2A, B+A}
Y2={-2B+A, -A, B+A, 3B-A}

X3={-6B+2A, -2B-2A, 2B+3A, 6B-A}
Y3={-2B-2A, -B+6A, 2B-6A, 3B+2A}

then we already know that in the in the grid
X1 x Y1
if the sum in the central
AxB is $4+\epsilon$
the sum in the surrounding
(2B-A)x(B-2A) is $\geq4+3\epsilon$,

similarly in the in the grid
(X1 $\cup$ X2) x (Y1 $\cup$ Y2)
if the sum in the central
AxB is $19/5+\epsilon$
then the sum in the surrounding
(2B-5A)x(5B-2A) is $\leq-19/5-21\epsilon$,

last, in the in the grid
(X1 $\cup$ X2 $\cup$ X3) x (Y1 $\cup$ Y2 $\cup$ Y3)
if the sum in the central
AxB is $254/67+\epsilon$
then the sum in the surrounding
(12B-3A)x(3B-12A) is $\geq254/67+135\epsilon$.

All of the above claims are easily verifiable with the tools already described in the previous answers and comments. I wonder if one can find sets X4 and Y4 (with 4 elements each?) to further improve the bound and maybe spot a general pattern.

Comment: I can confirm this result. Amazing! How did you find these grids?

Comment: @Tony, 1 and 2 by stripping down unnecessary grid points from the known results, and 3 by then trying to extrapolate 1 and 2, overshooting  big and stripping down again after (which is what I've been trying towards X4,Y4 without success).  The sequence 4,4,4 by the way may be misleading... the 1st set X1 maybe should be regarded as X0={0,A} U X1'={-B+A,B}, which makes the sequence 2,2,4,4 and suggests that X4,Y4 could have 6 or 8 points each, not 4.
More far fetched speculation: the sequence 3, 21, 135 looks like 2^2-1, 3*(2^3-1), 9*(2^4-1)...

Answer (score 1):

Using Yaakov's speed-up, I have run his original program with x-grid {m*A + n*B} + {0,A}, and y-grid {m*A + n*B} + {0, B}, for all m,n with |m| <= 4 and |n| <= 4. The program finds no improvement on 3.8 for a generic rectangle, so it looks (to me, anyway) as if this is the best that can be done using this method.

It also looks like we might be able to approach 3.8 arbitrarily closely with concrete examples, if only we had bigger and faster computers.